# asp.net website subdomain on fly with IIS url-rewrite-module

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, subdomain

I need to implement the sub domains in asp.net web forms (not MVC) for all clients on fly.
Here is the whole scenario I have a General website for every one as `http://mydomain.com`

and once a client is registered to my website, he will be allocated a subdomain as

```
client1.mydomain.com 
client2.mydomain.com 
client3.mydomain.com
```

and all clients will be served from

`http://mydomain.com/clientwebsite/`

with their customized contents from DB server On the Client website.

I looked about it and came to know that it can be done by IIS URL re Write but we will have multiple links and options on client sites which postbacks with querystring and data. I dont know how to send that and rewrite on backend. it can be

`client1.mydomain.com/mystoreitems` 
or

`client1.mydomain.com/section=mystoreitems`

Kindly guide me how to do this.